# How can I simulate a future date to test it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

One of my sprint tasks is to test whether an expiration date will change. Starting Feb 1st, this will expire on Sept 30th of the following year. Starting July 1st, it will expire on March 31st. I want to test whether this works or not but am drawing blanks as to how one could actually test this. I thought of maybe running locally and changing my system clock, but that didn't jive well with the database.

```
internal DateTime GetPowerPackageExpirationDate()
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Month >= 2 && DateTime.Now.Month <= 6) {
        return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, 09, 30);
    }
    else {
        return new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, 03, 31);
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to know a little bit more about your system.  Presumably you have some code that uses these dates that you can show us.

Comment: Mock the date. ..

Comment: hi, it is possible to put some piece of code that you are trying to validate?

Comment: Okay, so instead of using `DateTime.Now` directly in your code, write a function that gets the current date, you can then insert some code to return your own preferred date.

Comment: Changing your code just to make a test work is a code smell. Bad practice. Just mock the date. Check out `moq`, its pretty intuitive mocking library made for problems like this

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical use case which applies to `static`s in general:

best way to deal with it is to create a custom method, which can be mocked, to return the date.

example:

```
public interface IDateProvider
{
    DateTime Now { get; }
}
```

So, the concrete implementation you use in the code will return `DateTime.Now`

The test one; whatever you set it to return; future, past, etc.

Comment: Ack. I went to lunch waiting for the question to be reopened and you beat me to it. Had a whole answer typed in Notepad, LOL...

Comment: I'll have a look at your other answers ;-) @JuanR